# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: "Адресат вызова создал исключение."IOException: Файл "F:\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll" уже существует

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Security.AccessControl;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Win32;

using System.Net;

using System.Diagnostics;

using System.IO.Compression;

using System.Reflection.Emit;


namespace RC_Laun
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public string Version = "";
        public string ServerVersion = "";
        public string path = @"GameRC\";
        public string exename = "TEST.exe";
        public string url = "http://rchost/";
        public bool downloading = false;




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetFullPath(path));
            if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(path + exename)))
            {
                RegistryKey key;
                key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("RCGaims");
                key.SetValue("ver", "none");
                key.Close();
                Version = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                Version = (string)Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("RCGaims").GetValue("ver");
            }



            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "v.txt");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream reciveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readstream = null;
                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readstream = new StreamReader(reciveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readstream = new StreamReader(reciveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                string data = readstream.ReadToEnd();
                ServerVersion = data;
                readstream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

            label1.Text = Version + "/" + ServerVersion;

            if (Version != ServerVersion)
            {
                if (File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(path + exename)))
                {
                    button1.Text = "Обновить";
                    button1.Click += UpdateGaime;
                }
                else
                {
                    button1.Text = "Скачать";
                    button1.Click += UpdateGaime;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Text = "Поехали";
                button1.Click += Play;
            }

        }

        private void UpdateGaime(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            downloading = false;
            button1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(path));
            foreach (DirectoryInfo item in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                item.Delete(true);
            }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo item in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                item.Delete(true);
            }

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, g) => {
                    if (g.ProgressPercentage == 100)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(path + exename)))
                        {
                            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("game.zip", path);
                            RegistryKey key;
                            key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("RCGaims");
                            key.SetValue("ver", ServerVersion);
                            key.Close();
                            Version = ServerVersion;
                            label1.Text = Version + "/" + ServerVersion;

                            button1.Text = "Play";
                            button1.Click -= UpdateGaime;
                            button1.Click += Play;

                            button1.ForeColor = Color.White;
                        }
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                        downloading = false;
                    }
                };
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url + "Tukhtai_0.0.6.zip"), "game.zip");
            }
        }

        private void Play(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(path + exename);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //InitializeComponent
        }
    }
}
```

Часть в которой появляется ошибка

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RC_Laun
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с перезаписью файлов

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("game.zip", path, true);
```

если хотите, чтобы старые файлы заменялись на новые при распаковке